# Failed to load Google application default credentials docker

Tags: docker

```
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] /Users/li/.docker/ca.pem, /Users/li/.docker/key.pem or /Users/li/.docker/cert.pem does not exist, not using SSL
[DEBUG] Using configfile: /Users/li/.docker/config.json
[DEBUG] Failed to load Google application default credentials
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials (DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:111)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault (GoogleCredentials.java:103)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault (GoogleCredentials.java:76)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.googleContainerRegistryAuthSupplier (AbstractDockerMojo.java:352)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.authSupplier (AbstractDockerMojo.java:285)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.buildDockerClient (AbstractDockerMojo.java:178)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:148)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Using authentication suppliers: [ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier]
[DEBUG] Not using any build profile
[INFO] Copying /Users/li/SoftResourceSpace/Space/IDEA/ofit/eureka-server/target/eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -> /Users/li/SoftResourceSpace/Space/IDEA/ofit/eureka-server/target/docker/eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Copying src/main/docker/Dockerfile -> /Users/li/SoftResourceSpace/Space/IDEA/ofit/eureka-server/target/docker/Dockerfile
[INFO] Building image ofit/eureka-server
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.596 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-06T09:00:21+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default-cli) on project eureka-server: Exception caught: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.spotify.docker.client.messages.RegistryAuth: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('swarm')
[ERROR]  at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["stackOrchestrator"])
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default-cli) on project eureka-server: Exception caught
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exception caught
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:151)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.spotify.docker.client.messages.RegistryAuth: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('swarm')
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["stackOrchestrator"])
    at com.spotify.docker.client.auth.ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier.authForBuild (ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier.java:96)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.auth.MultiRegistryAuthSupplier.authForBuild (MultiRegistryAuthSupplier.java:77)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build (DefaultDockerClient.java:1371)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build (DefaultDockerClient.java:1348)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.buildImage (BuildMojo.java:580)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:360)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:149)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.spotify.docker.client.messages.RegistryAuth: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('swarm')
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["stackOrchestrator"])
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from (JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException (DeserializationContext.java:1456)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator (DeserializationContext.java:1012)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks (ValueInstantiator.java:370)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString (StdValueInstantiator.java:315)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString (BeanDeserializerBase.java:1283)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther (BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize (BeanDeserializer.java:150)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap (MapDeserializer.java:517)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize (MapDeserializer.java:362)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize (MapDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault (BeanDeserializerBase.java:1187)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject (BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize (BeanDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue (ObjectMapper.java:3770)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue (ObjectMapper.java:2099)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue (ObjectMapper.java:2596)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DockerConfigReader.parseDockerConfig (DockerConfigReader.java:94)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DockerConfigReader.fromConfig (DockerConfigReader.java:48)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.auth.ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier.authForBuild (ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier.java:94)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.auth.MultiRegistryAuthSupplier.authForBuild (MultiRegistryAuthSupplier.java:77)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build (DefaultDockerClient.java:1371)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build (DefaultDockerClient.java:1348)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.buildImage (BuildMojo.java:580)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:360)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:149)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Run `mvn package docker:build`.

My config is:

- Dockerfile:

  ```
  FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
  VOLUME /tmp
  ADD eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
  #RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
  ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
  EXPOSE 8761
  ```
- pom.xml: [image: I only have a screen shot of it]

Spring Boot: v2.0.4
Spring Cloud: Finchley SR1
IDEA
JDK 1.8
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a